# Django: How to add a new button in admin/index.html for specific model

Tags: django, django-admin

I am overriding the admin/index.html content block.
I have this inside:

```
{% for model in app.models %}
        <tr class="model-{{ model.object_name|lower }}">
        {% if model.admin_url %}
            <th scope="row"><a href="{{ model.admin_url }}">{{ model.name }}</a></th>
        {% else %}
            <th scope="row">{{ model.name }}</th>
        {% endif %}

        {% if model.add_url %}
            <td><a href="{{ model.add_url }}" class="addlink">{% trans 'Add' %}</a></td>
        {% else %}
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        {% endif %}

        {% if model.admin_url %}
            <td><a href="{{ model.admin_url }}" class="changelink">{% trans 'Change' %}</a></td>
        {% else %}
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        {% endif %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

and my model is:

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=False)
    price_percent_lower = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, null=False, default=1.3)
    price_percent_highter = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, null=False)
```

How can I create a new button like `<a href="{{ model.add_url }}" class="addlink">{% trans 'Add' %}</a>` pointing to a method named: **do_a_thing()** only for this model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to just call on template the do_a_thing this should work.

```
{% if model.object_name == 'Schedule' %}
<a href="{{ model.do_a_thing }}" class="custom-class">{% trans 'Do a thing' %}</a>
{% endif %}
```

And in model

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=False)
    price_percent_lower = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, null=False, default=1.3)
    price_percent_highter = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, null=False)

   @classmethod
   def do_a_thing(cls):
      ...
```

If you need add views here is a good post about that http://patrick.arminio.info/additional-admin-views/